# Flask not getting any data from jQuery request data

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I've a handler for a URL,

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def hello():
    ss=str(request.data)
    print ss
    return ss
```

The handler cannot retrive the data part of the request. When using jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax(
   {
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:"adasdasd",
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
      complete: function(xhr, statusText)
      {  alert(xhr.responseText) }})
```

nothing is returned

Comment: umm Maybe something is returned but you are not doing anything with it

Comment: Try using `ajax`'s success function and manipulate the data as you need too  `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array
A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.`

Comment: but I'm testing it with alert(xhr.responseText) , nothing is in the responseText

Comment: If you want to know what's inside the arguments print out `console.log(arguments)`.. it will give you the properties inside the object.. but if you want to handle the `data` do it inside the success function

Comment: yeps, i did this, the responsetext is ''

Comment: umm do you have a responseText property for your data?  try doing console.log(data)?  or console.log(data[0]);?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

In Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "enter your correct url",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify({title: 'My Title', article: 'My article'}),
  success: function(result){
    console.log(result)
  }
});
```

In Python (flask):

```
 from flask import request
 import json

 @app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
 def home():
   json_data = json.loads(request.data)
   print(json_data)
   return json_data
```

NOTE: The points are;

- JSON.stringify()
- contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
- json.loads
- request.data

Answer (score 19):

interesting, as it turns out you can only use `request.data` if the data was posted with a mimetype that flask can't handle, otherwise its an empty string `""` I think, the docs weren't very clear, I did some tests and that seems to be the case, you can take a look at the console output the flask generates when you run my tests.

> ## Incoming Request Data
>
> data 
>     Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Flask does not handle.

taken from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/

but since we are doing a standard `POST` using json `flask` can handle this quite well as such you can access the data from the standard `request.form` this `ss=str(request.form)` should do the trick as I've tested it.

As a side note `@crossdomain(origin='*')` this seems dangerous, theres a reason why we don't allow cross site ajax requests, though Im sure you have your reasons.

this is the complete code I used for testing:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from datetime import timedelta
from flask import make_response, request, current_app
from functools import update_wrapper


def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None,
                max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True,
                automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator



@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def hello():
    ss=str(request.form)

    print 'ss: ' + ss + ' request.data: ' + str(request.data)
    return ss


@app.route("/test/")
def t():
    return """
<html><head></head><body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery.ajax(
   {
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: "adasdasd",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
complete: function(xhr, statusText)
      {  alert(xhr.responseText) }})

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "/", false);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "unknown");
oReq.send('sync call');
alert(oReq.responseXML);
</script></body></html>
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

output:

```
$ python test.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012 02:45:28] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ss: ImmutableMultiDict([('adasdasd', u'')]) request.data: 
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012 02:45:28] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ss: ImmutableMultiDict([]) request.data: sync call
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012 02:45:28] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012 02:45:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

and my system:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.1

$ python -c 'import flask; print flask.__version__;'
0.8

$ uname -a
Darwin 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

using google chrome `Version 20.0.1132.57`

Answer (score 5):

I have been working with similar functionality and after a bit of messing around with the ajax and python, this is what I came up with for python reading the ajax data

JavaScript:

```
var data = {
      data: JSON.stringify({
                        "value":'asdf'
                    })
   }
};

$.ajax({
   url:"/",
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,
   success: function(msg){
              alert(msg);
            }
})
```

Python:

```
from flask import json
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    data = json.loads(request.form.get('data'))
    ss = data['value']
    return str(ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I get AJAX requests via `request.form`. I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and specify it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('#mgmtdata').dataTable( {
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "{{url_for('.xhr')|safe}}",
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                "bDeferRender": true,  
                "bFilter": {{ info.filter if info.filter else "false" }},
                "aoColumnDefs": [ {{ info.columndefs|safe if info.columndefs }} ],
        } );
} );
```

The xhr() function is simple:

```
@usersview.route('/xhr', methods=["POST"])
def xhr():
    if not 'usersview' in g:   
        g.usersview = UsersDatatableView()
    return g.usersview.render()
```

usersview is an instance of the my Grid() object. In this case, it's only interesting on how it get's to the ajax data that DataTables sent in:

```
def render(self):
    q = self.getQuery()

    # add filtering
    if 'sSearch' in request.form and request.form['sSearch']:
        q = self.applyFilter(q, request.form['sSearch'])

    # add sorting
    if 'iSortingCols' in request.form:
       # and so on
```