# Flask how to process file and data in form

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, flask

I'm trying to read a form containing an uploaded file in form with Flask 0.11.1 in Python 2.7.6.

```
app.route("/registration_submission")
def registration_submission():  
    print request.files
    print request.form
    print request.data
    # sth else...
```

Several methods I have tried give following results:
**(1) Pure HTML form**. It is like the following. The `name` field is contained according to [the W3S Note](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp), and the `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form id="register-form" action="/registration_submission" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><input type="text"id="firstname" name="firstname"></div>
    <div><input type="text"id="lastname" name="lastname"></div>
    <div><input type="file" id="resume" name="resume"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="send">Submit</button>
</form>
```

- The file can be retrieved from `request.form['filename']`
- `request.data` is empty. It is usually empty according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999990/get-raw-post-body-in-python-flask-regardless-of-content-type-header) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839855/flask-not-getting-any-data-from-jquery-request-data).

**(2) jQuery AJAX POST**. In addition to the HTML form used above, I set AJAX processData to false.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/registration_submission",
    data: submission_data,
    processData: false,
    error: function(response, error) {
            ;
        },
    success: function(data, code, jqxhr) {
            ;
        }
    });
```

- If the `submission_data` was acquired by `var submission_data = $('#form').serialize()` then:

  - `request.files` is empty
  - `request.form` contains all other information except the uploaded file, in pretty format
  - `request.data` is empty. But if I call it after calling `request.get_data()` then request.data is a nicely formatted url-style string
- If, however, I use `var submission_data = new FormData($('#form')[0])` then:

  - `request.files` is empty
  - `request.form` contains a messy blurb of encoded characters
  - `request.form.to_dict()` returns a dictionary of a messy blurb
  - `request.data` is empty. If I look for `request.data` after calling `request.get_data()` then it seems like `request.data` contains several thousand lines of information containing almost the whole html page.

Any idea to make jQuery AJAX form containing file and data retrievable in Flask? (I can't use option (1) since I need to do some checking before submitting the form). Thanks!

Comment: [See this as how to send multipart form data in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Ah adding the `contentType:false` works. Thank you!